# SQL Query Sum condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables namely the class_record, class_violation, violation.

The table class_record has these columns and data:

```
Class Violation CR No.            |        Class ID
000-000                           |        A30-000
000-001                           |        A30-000
```

The table class_violation has these columns and data:

```
Class Violation CR No.            |        Violation ID
000-000                           |        2
000-000                           |        1
000-001                           |        2
000-001                           |        4
000-001                           |        3
```

The table violation has these columns and data:

```
Violation ID                      |        First Amount  |        Second Amount
1                                 |        1000          |        2000
2                                 |        200           |        400
3                                 |        500           |        1000
4                                 |        500           |        1000
```

The table `class_record` contains the information of the class record.

The table `class_violation` is the table that contains what are the violations that is committed. And lastly, the table `violation` contains the information about the violations.

If the violation is committed twice, the second amount will be triggered instead of the first amount. As you can see on table `class_violation`, on `Violation ID` column, number 2 violation id is committed twice. The second amount of the must be the charged amount instead of the first amount. So the total charged amount will be the first amount plus the second amount if committed twice. My question is that how do I get the get the second amount instead of the first amount and get its total amount of the violations committed? So far here is my SQL query but is terribly wrong:

```
SELECT SUM(`First Amount`) 
FROM violation 
WHERE `Violation ID` 
        IN (SELECT `Violation ID` FROM class_violation 
            WHERE `Class Violation No.` 
                     IN (SELECT `Class Violation CR No.` 
                     FROM class_record WHERE `Class ID` = 'A30-000'))
```

Please help me. Sorry for my english. The result of the query must be:

```
SUM
2600
```

Here is my sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2712a

Comment: "So the total charged amount will be the first amount plus the second amount if committed twice" - it is mentioned in the question

Comment: first amount plus the second amount is 600 not 2600

Comment: 600 is for violation id 2, add first amount for violation id 1,3,4 alongwith it.

Comment: @echo_Me : violation id2 : 2 times. So first time 200 (FirstAmount), second time 400 (SecondAmount) So 200 +400 = 600. Then Violation id 1, 3, 4 (1 time each, so First amount) => 1000 + 500 + 500 = 2000. 2000 + 600 = 2600.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus ok thanks , well explained then the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by counting the violation ids for each whatever.  You can do this in a subquery using variables:

```
select sum(case when rn = 1 then v.`First Amount`
                when rn = 2 then v.`Second Amount`
           end)
from (select cv.*,
             @rn := if(@vi = `Violation ID`, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @vi := `Violation ID`
      from class_violation cv cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @vi := '') const 
      order by `Violation ID`
     ) cv join
     violation v
     on cv.`Violation ID` = v.`Violation ID` join
     class_record cr
     on cv.`Class Violation CR No.` = cr.`Class Violation CR No.`
where cr.`Class ID` = 'A30-000';
```

I would encourage you to rename the variables so you don't need the backticks.  For instance, name `First Amount` as `FirstAmount`.  It makes the queries easier to read and write.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus 200+400 is 600 how it comes 2600?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  Somehow when I looked at the results, I thought "2400" and "2600" were the same.  Obviously, I missed that the violations are counted independently of the first columns.  But all fixed now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yep, +1 and that's a min ;)

Comment: Hello if I would ask again, if there is a third offense amount, what would be the SQL query?

Comment: That's what i've been doing for hours if you would mind answering.

Comment: @user3233787 . . . You would add the clause `where rn = 3 then ThirdAmount`, or something like that

Comment: Sir if you would mind helping me again (sorry for bothering) is that I added the "where rn = 3" on the SUM function but I get the wrong result in my table. Should I add some code on the if statement?

Comment: @user3233787 . . . No, the `if` statement should be fine.  You can run the subquery separately to be sure it is producing the right violation counts.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot I will try separating the subquery.

Comment: Sir this will be the last time that I will be bothering you again sorry. I still get the wrong result. I guess its in the part where @rn + 1 when it triggers. The scenario is that I added the third offense amount and committed the same violation more than 3 times. When it is committed more than 3 times, the violation amount is still on the third offense amount. My result is that it will not count anymore I guess on the rn + 1 because rn will be 4. Am I wrong? Sorry for my english.

Comment: @user3233787 . . . Then add `else ThirdAmount` to the `case` statement.

Comment: I get it now. It should be where rn > 2 so that it will still count even though rn will be 4 and above. Thank you so much!

Comment: yes sir that should be the best solution instead of using the greater than sign. Thanks a lot!